# amCharts v5 custom plugins

Tags: reactjs, plugins, amcharts

Is it possible to create a custom plugin for amCharts v5? If so where can I find this information e.g. a lasso for items selections.

Also are there any plugins which allow to export the page and charts to PowerPoint?